why $U_2 + W = \mathbb R^2$?
I was reading this question here:
If $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $U_1 + W = U_2 + W$ then $U_1 = U_2$?
Here is the answer provided there:
Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, and $U_1 = \overline{\{(0,1)\}}$, $W = \overline{\{(1,0)\}}$,$U_2 = \overline{\{(1,1)\}}$. Note that $U_1 \cap W = U_2 \cap W = \{ 0\}$, and $U_1 + W = U_2 + W = \mathbb{R}^2$. From here, it follows that $U_1 \oplus W = U_2 \oplus W = \mathbb{R}^2$, but $U_1 \neq U_2$.
My question is:
why $U_2 + W = \mathbb R^2$? Could someone explain this to me please? How will we get the point $(1,1) \in \mathbb R^2$ for example? Is not the first coordinate always double the second one?

$0(1,0)+1(1,1)=(1,1)$

ok thanks for answering my last question, how can I prove my first question?@EthanBolker

What is your first question? Two  of your sentences have question marks. I answered the first. The answer to the second is "no". If you are asking about the linked question, that one is of the form "true or false" and it's false, as the linked answer shows.

why $U_2 + W = \mathbb R^2$? This is the question I want a proof to it @EthanBolker

Prove $U_2+W=\mathbb{R}^2$
For any $\mathbb{x}\in U_2+W$
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{x}&=a(1,0)^T+b(1,1)^T\text{ for some }a,b\\
&=(a+b)(1,0)^T+b(0,1)^T\\
&\in\mathbb{R}^2
\end{align}$$
So $U_2+W\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$.
For any $\mathbb{y}\in\mathbb{R}^2$
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{y}&=a(1,0)^T+b(0,1)^T\text{ for some }a,b\\
&=(a-b)(1,0)^T+b(1,0)^T+b(0,1)^T\\
&=(a-b)(1,0)^T+b(1,1)^T\\
&\in U_2+W
\end{align}$$
So $\mathbb{R}^2\in U_2+W$
Thus $U_2+W=\mathbb{R}^2$
